# How do I exit a stored procedure when I encounter a null value in a column?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I have a source table in BigQuery into which data is ingested from CSV files. The source table has a column named "ingestDate" of type DATETIME. The destination table's structure is exactly the same as the source.

**SOURCE TABLE:**

| ID | ingestDate | Column1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 113 | 2022-06-02T00:00:00 | Value4 |
| 112 | null | Value3 |
| 111 | 2022-06-01T00:00:00 | Value2 |
| 110 | 2022-05-31T00:00:00 | Value1 |

**DESTINATION TABLE:**

| ID | ingestDate | Column1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2022-06-01T00:00:00 | Value2 |
| 110 | 022-05-31T00:00:00 | Value1 |

I'm need to write a **stored procedure** to do the following:

- Copy all the latest values into destination table from the source table. (This is simple enough by comparing the timestamps and I can get this done)
- If there are any null values in column "ingestDate" within the source table, then **throw an error** and exit the stored procedure without mapping any data at all.

Here is some additional information:

- Column "ingestDate" does not have a NOT NULL clause, and there is no way for me to modify the structure of the table to include one.
- I am also trying to get the procedure to return the number of new rows inserted.

This is the procedure I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dataset.sample1()
BEGIN

    DECLARE sourceCount, initDestCount, finalDestCount INT64;
    DECLARE latestIngestDate DATETIME;

    SET sourceCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset.sourceTable);
    SET initDestCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset.destTable);
    SET latestIngestDate = (SELECT MAX(ingestDate) FROM dataset.destTable);

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dataset.destTable (
            ID, 
            ingestDate, 
            Column1)

        SELECT
            CAST(ID AS INT64),
            CAST(ingestDate AS DATETIME),
            CAST(Column1 AS STRING)

        FROM
            dataset.sourceTable

        WHERE
            ingestDate > latestIngestDate

    END;

SET finalDestCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset.destTable);

SELECT sourceCount, initDestCount, finalDestCount;

END;
```

Can someone please help me implement the error mechanism that I was looking to implement in the procedure above? Any help with optimizing this script would also be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: why can't you just add `and ingestDate is not null` to your where clause?  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#is_operators

Answer (score 0):

change the where like this

```
    WHERE
        ingestDate is not null and
        ingestDate > latestIngestDate
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#is_operators

---

Based on comment -- I'd add a flag to the return, throwing exceptions is VERY slow and generally considered a poor choice for flow of control.

```
SET errorFlag = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dataset.sourceTable where ingestDate is null;

SELECT sourceCount, initDestCount, finalDestCount, errorFlag;
```

Comment: This would be very effective at selecting the rows that do not have null values. However, I also need to raise an error in the first place to indicate that the source table has rows with null values.

Also, let's say that the first time the procedure is executed, it skips all rows with null values. Let's say that in a future ingest, these values are corrected in the ingest table. Then when I run the procedure again, those corrected rows will not be copied to the destination table, right?

Comment: @Echo-Victor58 -- see edit :)

Comment: That's a good idea. But how I would I stop the script from executing itself for all records, instead of just the records that have null values in the ingestDate column?

Comment: @Echo-Victor58 -- I don't understand -- it has a where statement -- that is what a where statement does -- only count the ones which are null

Comment: Apologies! Let me elaborate on my requirement.

The code suggested here with the error flag and the where condition would, in my understanding, select all records where the ingestDate is not null and insert them into the target table. The "errorFlag" variable would get a count of all records where ingestDate is null and present them as the output to the stored procedure when it's called. But the procedure still executes completely and all non-null records are inserted into the target table.

What needs to happen, is that the procedure should not execute at all and throw an error.

Comment: @Echo-Victor58 -- Nope.  My recommendation was to use my prior note to not insert the null items and then 2nd select to get the count.  The null items would not be inserted.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But my requirement here is to not insert ANY items at all if there are any nulls found in the source records. The requirement here is to, by some means, abort the entire procedure and not insert any values into the target if there are nulls.

Comment: @Echo-Victor58 -- ok then put this check at the start and add an if statement that returns before executing the insert.  (The requirement to do nothing if there is a null seems to me to be driven by the way exceptions work not by normal business requirements to me -- I've never heard of a rollback if there is bad data before -- usually you want to process as much data as you can)